# Format Query results while querying

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

My data is structured as follows, and for simple queries it does return it in this way:

```
{  
  'props':{  
     'prop1':'value1',
     'prop2':'value2',
     'prop3':'value3',
  },
  'some_id':'123',
  'timestamp':'1970-01-02 23:25:37'
}
```

Code used for querying:

```
response = table.query(        
  KeyConditionExpression=Key('some_id').eq(some_id),        
  ProjectionExpression="#p.#p1, #s",
  ExpressionAttributeNames={'#p': 'props', '#p1': 'prop1', '#s': 'some_id'}
  )
```

Result with current code:

```
{
  'some_id': '123',
  'props': {
    {
      'prop1':'value1'
    }
  }
}
```

But my desired result is flattened:

```
{ 
  'some_id': '123',
  'prop1': 'value1'
}
```

So the question is - how do I get the desired result with the query, not with python after getting the resuts.

Answer (score -1):

Without trying to set up a full test environment for this, it looks like the nested format is the projection you're explicitly requesting. I'd try this:

```
response = table.query(        
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('some_id').eq(some_id),        
    ProjectionExpression="#p1, #s",
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#p1': 'prop1', '#s': 'some_id'}
)
```

Since you don't actually want `#p` or the nesting at all, I removed it from both the attribute names and the projection.

Comment: A downvote with no explanation; not very constructive. If the OP was getting the results he posted from the query he posted, this should result in exactly what he asked for. At least explain yourself.